# How to remove white margins around div element and image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to remove the whitespace around my header photo, which should cover the entirety of the page. I'm running a local server on my computer (localhost) to test this PHP file.

I've already tried all of the relevant answers I could find here on Stack Overflow. I've looked up multiple threads and done the following:
1) reset the CSS styles by changing margins and padding to 0
2) surrounded the image tag with body tags, which should now be reset
3) Changed the width setting to 100% and height to auto

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<body>
<div class="container">
    <img class="image" 
src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0533/2089/files/header- 
design-position-absolute_fcabc9a2-0fdb-4057-a6fb-f84f16840eba.png? 
v=1507118933" alt="Header Picture">
    <div class="name"> ⏤ NAME ⏤ </div>
<div class="tagline"> traveler. consultant. developer.</div>
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```

style.css:

```
* { 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
}
/* container holding both the header photo and text */
.container {
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
     color: white;
} 
/* main header image */
.image {
    filter: drop-shadow(8px 8px 10px gray); filter: contrast(75%);
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
/* name text */
.name {
    position: absolute;
    top: 17.5%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 600%;
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
}
/* tagline text */
.tagline {
    position: absolute;
    top: 23.5%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 200%;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
```

All I want is for there to be no white space around the picture such that it stretches across the page. Instead, I keep getting white space around the edges that I can't get rid of.

**Upadte** I'm implementing some of the changes now and seeing why suddenly this simplified version works. It must be something in the rest of my code (which I have not included) Let me reupdate this code with the rest of it first.

Comment: Provide your screenshot with problem. Its actually working here as you need.

Comment: The only white space I can see is the descender at the bottom, which you can solve with `vertical-align:top;` or `display:block`

Comment: I think your picture has white spaces by itself, I tested your code here and it works http://jsfiddle.net/5bLv4rzw/

Comment: The image has no proper height to stretch all the window. change the mage and try

Answer (score 1):

This works fine when tested locally and on jsfiddle. However your HTML is missing a `<head>` tag. The CSS `<link>` should go inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion here is to use the background-image CSS property as then you gain more control over the image box, and you can then set the actual page body or section to render the image.

```
.your-image {
  background-image: url("photographer.jpg"); /* The image used */
  background-color: #cccccc; /* Used if the image is unavailable */
  height: 500px; /* You must set a specified height */
  background-position: center; /* Center the image */
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the image */
  background-size: cover; /* Resize the background image to cover the entire container */
}
```

One thing to note is that the `<img>` tag is included in screen readers while background images are not, making your website more user-friendly to those who use screen readers as the background here is less relevant to the content.

One thing to think about is that all HTML elements have their own predefined margins and padding as well as other attributes based on the browser they are rendered in, an example of this is the 8px margin placed on the `<body>` element by default in most browsers, which can be overwritten in your code by being explicitly defined.

Just as a side note, there are some libraries that assist with the incongruencies between our different browsers and how they render our elements, I would take a look at [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) which is a great CSS only library with plenty of documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem  in your image so, try to crop the image.

```css
* { 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
}
/* container holding both the header photo and text */
.container {
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
     color: white;
} 
/* main header image */
.image {
    filter: drop-shadow(8px 8px 10px gray); filter: contrast(75%);
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
/* name text */
.name {
    position: absolute;
    top: 17.5%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 600%;
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
}
/* tagline text */
.tagline {
    position: absolute;
    top: 23.5%;
    left: 40%;
    transform: translate(-30%, 50%);
    font-size: 200%;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body style=" background-color: #000000">
<div class="container">
    <img class="image" 
src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Header Picture">
    <div class="name"> ⏤ NAME ⏤ </div>
<div class="tagline"> traveler. consultant. developer.</div>
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```